# At what time do copyrights expire?

Tags: united-states, copyright

Expiring copyright terms end at the beginning of the new year. At what time does this happen? Presumably it's midnight, but in what time zone?

Answer (score 2):

### At midnight

[australia](/questions/tagged/australia)

The [Copyright Act](https://www.legislation.gov.au/C1968A00063/latest/text) 1968 simply states that copyright lasts until the end of the calendar year, that is, just before midnight on 31 December.

While the Commonwealth does have Constitutional power over weights and measures (including time), it has only legislated to the extent of requiring the states to use the UTC system. Which time zone a state or part of a state (the far west of NSW is in the same time zone as SA for example) is in and whether they observe daylight savings is a matter for each state.

Therefore, while the work becomes public domain at midnight on 1 January; that will not be the same tick of the UTC clock in different places. The earliest will be Norfolk Island at (NFDT) UTC+12 and the last will be the Cocos and Keeling Islands at CXT (UTC+6:30), giving the owner 5.5 hours more protection - the former is  a daylight saving time, which would be in place on 1 January.

AFAIK, this has never been an issue in a copyright case.